# SSD - unable to initalize, is it dead?

Tags: ssd, data-recovery

SSD went dead just after a standard booting of Windows 10. I cannot connect to it ever since. I tried:
-Windows Recovery Tool
-Updating drivers
-Connecting SSD to another computer, but I cannot initialize it in Disk Manager as it shows 'fatal error'
Is there anything else I can try to recover data from it?

Comment: Send it to a data recovery company.

Comment: ... And next time keep backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does sound like you are likely to have suffered catastrophic failure but you could try using a SMART monitoring tool to assess the drive health. This might give you more debugging information and make some progress (even if just confirming failure). A few options for Windows are available here (some of these are commercial software):

http://carlcheo.com/best-smart-monitoring-tools

You could also try plugging it into a Linux and/or macOS machine to see if it's readable with a different OS. The Ubuntu Live USB distribution would be a good starting point for this.